# Delphi and C/C++ DLL

Tags: c++, c, delphi, memory-management, dll

I have a delphi application that uses BTMemoryModule and imports/calls functions from a DLL.
The DLL is written in C/C++.

The delphi application sends an original pwidechar (array of 4 bytes or array of widechars) to a function.

I have no C/C++ pseudo code but it looks like this:

```
type
 TMyFunc = function ( p  : pointer ): pointer; stdcall;

procedure anynamehere();
var
 Addr     : TMyFunc;
 MyString : WideString;
begin
 [...]
  Addr := BTMemoryGetProcAddress('mydll.dll', 'ExportedFunc');
  MyString := 'TEST';
 [...]
 ExportedFunc (pwidechar(MyString));
 MessageBoxW (0, pwidechar(MyString), '', 0);
end;
```

The DLL should now have the original pointer to the MyString var.
The procedure in the delphiapp stays active (until the dll ExportedFunc is finished). 
So the MyString var gets NOT disposed after the procedure ends.
My question now is:
Is it possible to CHANGE the value of MyString within the DLL? (technically possible...) But How? The string is null terminated so the user knows how long the pointer length is. But if the C++ DLL changes the value , doesn't have the user also alloc new space or something? Or does this happen automatically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your actual requirement? And are you at liberty to modify the DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLL is welcome to change the pointed-to memory if it wants, and it doesn't need to know the address of `MyString`, either. It only needs to know the address *stored in* `MyString`, which is exactly what you pass to it already. Since the function receives a pointer to a null-terminated array of `WideChar` values, the function should be declared like this:

```
void* __stdcall ExportedFunc(wchar_t* arg);
```

It can find out the length of the buffer with [`wcslen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx), and then modify the contents of the buffer in the usual ways. For example:

```
{
  size_t const len = wcslen(arg);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    if (arg[i] == 'a')
      arg[i] = 'e';
  return 0;
}
```

You can have it return some other pointer value if you wish, but since the caller ignores it, it doesn't really matter in this situation.

When the caller assigned a value to `MyString`, space was allocated automatically by the OS on the program's behalf via [`SysAllocString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458.aspx). The caller then passes that buffer to the DLL, and the DLL can modify it. The caller doesn't need to do anything special with the buffer afterward. Delphi will call `SysFreeString` automatically when the calling function ends and `MyString` goes out of scope.

You could also remove the `PWideChar` type cast and declare the function to receive a `WideString` in Delphi, a `BSTR` in C++. You could do all the same string manipulations in the DLL in addition to using [`SysStringLen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221240.aspx) instead of `wcslen`. You could pass `MyString` directly to the function:

```
ExportedFunc(MyString);
```

Comment: thank you. That sounds good. So let me get this right. If the C/C++ DLL actually changes the value of the string (for example change it completly and makes it longer, sets a #0 at the end) it automatically allocates and realings, etc. so the delphi app can use the modified widestring as usual?

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss The only way for re-allocations to find their way back to Delphi is if you pass the `WideString` by reference. You currently are passing `WideString` by value.

Comment: I said nothing about re-allocation, Benjamin. The DLL can modify the *contents* of the string, and those changes will be reflected on the calling side, too, just as expected. The function cannot make the buffer longer (or shorter) because that would involve freeing the buffer and allocating a new one, and the function as currently declared and used does not provide enough information to modify all the values that it would need to in order to make the re-allocation effective. (You could pass the function a `PWideString`, and then it could re-allocate the BSTR.)

Comment: PwideString sounds good. I think I'm going with that one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ code can alter the content of the pwidechar array that is passed in, but it would not be able to change the length of the string as understood by delphi, as the C++ code doesn't understand delphi-style strings natively. All it receives is a `wchar *` parameter.

If you wanted to make major changes to the string e.g. make it longer, then you would need to allocate at least as much space as you wanted in the caller by using `SetLength(MyString, size)`, and then check the length on return, so you then call `SetLength(MyString, retSize)` on the string to make it the returned size.

Again, usual caveats against buffer overruns and the like.

I notice that the function returns a pointer; if the C++ code is allocating memory using `new()`, then you will have no possibility of managing this memory from the Delphi code as the two memory allocation systems are different.

Comment: It's not a Delphi string, it's a COM BSTR

Comment: Old reference on my behalf. Never looked under the hood of the WideString delphi implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The DLL is passed a pointer to the buffer. It is perfectly possible for the DLL to modify that buffer. The DLL can modify any of the 4 wide characters that your code passes to it. It could also modify the fifth character, the null-terminator.

However, the DLL cannot create a new buffer and have the calling code see that new buffer.

Comment: so you're saying I can modify it from "TEST" to "FOO1" but not to "FOO11"?

Comment: That is precisely what I am saying.